# WPFのListviewでリストを横スクロールさせたい

Tags: .net, wpf

Windows 7 上の VisualStudio 2013 Community で開発をしております。

Windows フォームの `Listview` では `View` プロパティで `List` を選択すると
縦幅一杯に表示されたら横列へ表示され横スクロールが表示されるのですが、
WPF の `Listview` では同様の動きをさせることはできますでしょうか？

Comment: 「縦幅一杯に表示されたら横列へ表示され横スクロールが表示される」部分について、もう少し補足がほしいところです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
イメージとしては、
Windowsのエクスプローラの右ペインでファイルを「一覧」形式で表示した時と同様のイメージです。
「一覧」の時は横スクロールのみが表示され、ファイルのリストは左上から右下へならんでいる、まさにこの動きです。

Comment: [Custom ListBox Layout in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18561/Custom-ListBox-Layout-in-WPF) のようなイメージですか? この記事のは並び方向が違うと思いますが…。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
かなりイメージが近いですが、縦方向に出力しきれない分を右の列へ折り返したいので、リンク先の画像の縦横逆というイメージです。

ちなみに yukitos さんの回答でほぼイメージ通りの動きとなりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPFの`ListView`とのことなので回答からは外れるかもしれませんが、
`ScrollViewer`と`WrapPanel`を組み合わせることで同様の機能が実現できると思います。

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" ItemWidth="100">
        <TextBlock Text="sample text"/>
        <TextBlock Text="sample text"/>
        <TextBlock Text="sample text"/>
        <TextBlock Text="sample text"/>
        <TextBlock Text="sample text"/>
        <TextBlock Text="sample text"/>
        <TextBlock Text="sample text"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

なお`WrapPanel`の`Height`と`ItemWidth`の値は横スクロールバーを表示するためのデバッグ用なので
実際には設定不要です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
いろいろ試させていただいて、これが一番イメージに近かったです。

Answer (score 2):

ItemsPanelを設定する場合はこうです。内部のStackPanelはWrapPanelやUniformGridに変えても良いです。

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
試してみましたが、横方向に１行のみのリスト表示となってしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

以下のコードがおそらく一番想定通りに動くと思います。

`ListView` のパネル部分を `WrapPanel` に差し替えて、`ListView` が内部的に持つ
`ScrollViewer` に上下のスクロールバーを出さないように設定しています。

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
yukitosさんの情報と同じく
一番イメージに近かったです。

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewerを使えばできるかと思います。

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```